# generate a route to mvc controller action in automapper valueresolver

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, automapper

I am working with automapper and have a value resolver. Within the resolver I would like to create a link to a mvc route, prefably using T4MVC or any other means. The result from my controller is the url in strong form of the route.

How can I set this up? Is it possible?